# Error: unknown class: 'message' - how to fix that?

Tags: android, android-intent

I just started teaching myself android development and I am running into an error on this basic hello world application.

I tried searching but everything seems like chinese language to me.

here is the tutorial i was following: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity

and here is a screenshot of my error:
[I will include the code below][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xm1tg.png

```
<code>
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
}

// Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

// Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(message);//on this line i get an error under "message"
</code>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: I would suggest you learn basics of java/kotlin before starting your android app development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move that code in onCreate() method like :

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but could you elaborate more on why it works this way. Doesn't declaring message outside the onCreate method make it a global variable?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the following code inside `onCreate()`

```
// Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

// Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(message);//on this line i get an error under "message"
```